# CSS: small icon doesn't break at paragraph break in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have an issue that I cannot solve solely.

I have this CSS:

```
.APm2 {
    background: transparent url(images/arrow_h.gif) center right no-repeat;
    padding-right: 13px;
    zoom: 1;
}
a.APm2 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000 !important;
}
a.APm2:hover { 
    background: transparent url(images/arrow_h_over.gif) center right no-repeat;
}
```

HTML (Portion:)

```
<strong>
    <a class="APm2" href="#H1" onClick="abre_fecha('H',1);CarregaLegendasFileAttr_UI_Ajax('H',1);">
        Pensão de Preço de Sangue e Pensão por Serviços Excecionais e Relevantes Prestados ao País
    </a>
</strong>
<p></p>
```

The text breaks at "Relevantes" and goes to the next line, but the icon doesn't go with the line. i.e., the icon doesn't sit near the word "País"
If the line doesn't break, for instance, the icon sets pretty good.

It works in FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari... it doesn't works in IE.

Anyone knows how to put the icon properly? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in a http://jsfiddle.net. I am not sure what this looks like by your description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `span` inside the `a` tag, and apply the background to that, see: http://jsfiddle.net/g2nLV/2/

```
<strong>
    <a href="#H1" class="APm2" onClick="abre_fecha('H',1);CarregaLegendasFileAttr_UI_Ajax('H',1);">
    Pensão de Preço de Sangue e Pensão por Serviços Excecionais e Relevantes Prestados ao País <span class="APm2-icon"></span></a>
</strong>
```

With this CSS:

```
span.APm2-icon {
    /*obviously set the below background to your icon, not just a colour */
    background: green;
    /* same width and height as your icon dimensions*/
    width: 13px;
    height:13px;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
}

a.APm2 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000 !important;
}

span.APm2-icon:hover { 
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! It worked fine! But now it doesn't work in FF... lol. Thanks anyway I will try to figure out myself.

Comment: I used *display: inline-block for IE only and voila.

Comment: I bet you have Compatibility View enabled in your IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the "correct" behavior in IE8, I had the same exact problem and the only solution was to simply take out the icon for browsers that didn't support the icon 'wrapping' properly and aligning to the ending word in the second line.

1. If you're using an IEx style sheet inside a Conditional Comment, then you know what to do.
2. If you're using the, what I call, *"PICCH" (read "Pikachu") technique, then you would just do: `.ie8 .APm2 { background:none; }`
3. If you're not using any of the above two and are only using a single CSS file, you can do: `.APm2/*\**/ { background:none; }`. Note: If you're using LESS to preprocess your CSS, this hack won't work, LESS is unable to compile this, and that's a good thing.
4. You could also try: `.APm2 { background:none\0/; }`. Some will say that you could also do: `.APm2 { background:none\9; }` but the problem with that is that IE9 and IE10 will see it too.

See more IE6/7/8/9/10/11 CSS hacks here: https://gist.github.com/ricardozea/5549389

Man, I hate having to resort to these kinds of things, but we sometimes don't have any other options :/

Also, in your code `.APm2` and `a.APm2` are the same, so you might as well make a single rule with all those properties. If you're going to do that, I suggest you use `.APm2` so as to not incur into specificity issues in the future.

Hope this helps.

(*) The "Pikachu" technique, PICCH, means: "Paul Irish's Conditional Comments in the Head" which of course we all know since 2008: [Conditional Stylesheets vs CSS Hacks? Answer: Neither!](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)

Comment: Thank you for your awsome insight about this problem but your examples failed to work properly.

Comment: Hmmm... you said IE8 and those are IE8 hacks, I've used them for years. I'm almost sure you have Compatibility View enabled in IE8 and are seeing your site as IE7, that's why your solution `*display: inline-block;` worked because the "Star Hack" only works in IE6 and IE7.

Comment: I'm gonna check that Ricardozea, probably you're right.